# Disable disqus on pages

Tags: disqus

I have installed [Disqus Comment System](http://wordpress.org/plugins/disqus-comment-system/) 2.74 in my Worpress version 3.5.2.
I want to disable disqus from all pages except Blog post.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the source and took a look, I see that Disqus hooks onto the `comments_template` filter so you can try this;

```
//hook onto comments_template filter with priority 1
add_filter( 'comments_template' , 'disable_disqus', 1 );

function disable_disqus($file) {

   //if not blog page, remove disqus filter
   if( !is_page('blog') ) {

      remove_filter('comments_template', 'dsq_comments_template');

   }
   //returns regular comments template
   return $file;
}
```

Comment: I didn't undersand where this code will be added???

Comment: within your theme functions.php file

Answer (score -2):

just go to "Pages" and find the page you don't want disqus comments on. Then click on "edit" and look for the "discussion tab. Under "Discussion, simply uncheck "allow comments".

This is how it appears in my wordpress, using the optimizepress 2.0 theme + disqus.

Comment: There is no link to the plugin you mention and no one to the theme. Also you are, due to updates, pointing to a moving target. This answer will be useless for later visitors in the near future.